# What is a shoebox app?

Tags: macos, icloud

This is taken from the OSX iCloud Storage reference document:

> If you're writing a shoebox app, on the other hand, you should not use
>   NSDocument. So if you're doing a shoebox app, you must implement your
>   own file presenter and deal with version conflicts through that API.

What is a shoebox app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A single-window or library style app. See the [Mac App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html), specifically **The App Style Determines the Core Architecture** section.